# How to use Hi(r8-r12) register in Cortex-m0?

Tags: gcc, arm, cpu-registers, thumb

In ARM/Thumb architecture, there are 16(r0-r15) registers in a single cpu. Furthermore, Thumb-Instruction-Set can only use the first 8(r0-r7) registers and the r13,r14 and r15 register.But the last 5(r8-r12) register are still in the cpu. How can we use these Hi(r8-r12) registers?

Recently, I am designing a protecting scheme in ARM Cortex-M0 CPU. In my project, I want to use r9 and r10 to store some information. Because other instructions would not use these registers, so I don`t need to push and pop these registers.

Can anyone help me with these? Should I use BX or BLX instruction to switch instruction set?

[Instruction I use the r9 register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ihvk.png)

[Wrong information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms5hd.png)

Comment: You may just miss a `.syntax unified` statement in your assembler source file.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that in ARMv6-M architecture, few instructions accept high registers. The most notable of them is `mov` (not `movs`). This way, you can read in any of the lower registers from memory then move these values from the low register to the high register you want. An example code:

```
LDR  r0, [r1]     ; read into r0 the value at address r1
MOV  r9, r0       ; move the recent read value to r9
```

This way, you can make use of the high register.
I hope this helps, though a little late :)

Comment: Yet later, but in case anyone else is looking for this information, the list of instructions that can access high registers is: `add`, `blx`, `bx`, `cmp` and `mov`.

Answer (score 1):

Cortex-M0 only supports Thumb instruction set (and some instructions from Thumb2). So, there is no possibility of instructionset switching from Thumb to ARM.

Reference: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M#Instruction_sets

ARM documentation from http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0040d/Bgbbfcgc.html gives little hint about possible usages high-registers.

[If time permits, I will tryout somethings and will update this post soon]